# Migrating mariadb 10.1 databases to a mariadb 10.3 database

Tags: import, mariadb

I have a sql dump file generated by mysqldump of a mariadb 10.1 database
I have set up a new db server using mariadb 10.3 and am trying to import data and structure coming from the sql dump file. I get many errors like :-

**You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '
INDEX `user_id` (`user_id` ASC) VISIBLE,
INDEX `item_id` (`item_id` ASC)...' at line 17.
SQL Error: 1064

- Creating table event-afs-u-139492.wp_bp_activity_meta**

My question is, Is there anyway of upgrading the 10.1 SQL dump file to 10.3 before importing ?

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: What is the syntax cause of the error? Not enough information here to know. Depending upon what that might be, the could be way to use a script to modify before import.

Comment: Recommend testing with `mysqldump --no-data` to only get the table structure. What is `show create table wp_bp_activity_meta` on your 10.1 server?